# Socrata API and alternative HTTP client for cURL

Tags: curl, socrata

For the Socrata API, is there an alternative HTTP client that can be used instead of cURL?  Our network currently blocks the ports required for cURL.  If cURL is the only or best way, then please send me the ports that would need to be opened in our firewall.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much any HTTP client or library can be used with the Socrata API. cURL is just used for examples because it's the lowest common denominator.

However, if you say the "ports needed by cURL" are blocked by your firewall, you'll probably need them opened regardless of what HTTP client you use.

We use the standard ports - 80 for HTTP and 443 for HTTPS.